# get the id of the parent of the parent div using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following code and I need to have the id of the post in jquery! please help me in this.

```
foreach($posts->result() as $post){ 
    echo "<div class='post' id='$post->id' >";
       echo $post->content;
       echo "<div class='commentor' id='commentor' >";
          echo "<input type='text' class='commentor_input' />";
       echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

I have tried getting the code of the post using the code bellow but is not working!

```
$('.commentor_input').change(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var post_id = $(this).closest("div").find(".post").attr("id");
    alert(post_id); // alerts Undefined!
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `closest("div.post")`

```
var post_id = $(this).closest("div.post").attr("id");
```

`closest` returns the first element matching your selector, so it returned `div.commentor` in your case, and `.find` couldn't find any `.post` inside it, therefore the `undefined`.

Comment: Umm, I don't get the 3 downvotes I got on this answer. Could any downvoter please explain?

Comment: Looks like 2 of the downvoters got banned from this site today.

Answer (score 3):

Just change `.find()` to `.parent()`.

```
$('.commentor_input').change(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var post_id = $(this).closest("div").parent(".post").attr("id");
    alert(post_id); // alerts Undefined!
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w6SAa/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.commentor_input').change(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var comment = $(this).val();
    var post_id = $(this).parents("div.post").attr("id");
    alert(post_id); // alerts Undefined!
});
```

Docs [jquery.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents)